# option:selected not triggering .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown box that has a list of institutions in it. Now if I manually select an option, it works and I am able to grab the correct value.

However, I have a select rates button which uses JavaScript to pull up a rate sheet. You select a rate from that sheet and it will select an option from the dropdown for you (one that corresponds with the rate from the rate sheet). If I use this method, it doesn't trigger a .change() therefor I can't get a value for the selected option.

```
$('#id_financial_institution').change(function () {
          var value = $("#id_financial_institution option:selected").text()
          $("fi").text(value);
});
```

Any suggestions? I have tried `.change()` and `.click()` but nothing.

Comment: besides $fi , yous said :"You select a rate from that sheet and it will populate the dropdown", after that do you select values from the dropdown? I couldnt get how do u select values, and if u do not select values, u get nothing. 
Also, $("#id_financial_institution option:selected") might return you an array.

Comment: It would probably help more if we saw an example output of the relevant portions of html you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went inside my AJAX call and got the value of the fields I needed there.  For some reason, when using the AJAX call, it wouldn't fire the .change() on that particular field.

Thanks for all your input everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in the change function you don't have to do another search or selector because you already have the object you just have to find the selected option from it. So you can try this:

```
$('#id_financial_institution').change(function () {
          var value = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
          $("fi").text(value);
});
```

If the code still doesn't return you answer start to add alerts at each point to see where you are and what values you have and work your way from there?

Comment: alright I placed an alert() before I declare the variable and it doesn't trigger unless I manually change the dropdown option. Hmmm.. I'm not sure what to do now?

Comment: Excellent, that is a great start. You can trigger the $('#id_financial_institution') combo box change event by setting the selected index or selected value programatically. In other words, once the rate is selected from your list get the key or value from the list that correspond to the item in the combo box and set it. $('#id_financial_institution').val([your value or key from the list]);

Comment: You actually may want to do the inverse use jQuery to fire the click event of your list item and you can use a simple class for it e.g. `$(".mylistitem").click(function(){ $('#id_financial_institution').val($(this).text()); });` The .text may be different depending on the type of element in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `.text()` use `.val()`

```
$(function() {
    $('#id_financial_institution').change(function () {
          var value = $("#id_financial_institution option:selected").val()
         alert(value);
});

})
```

Here is a sample demo, without your html. I am just alerting the value.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GAVwN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this all wrong. You already have the `select` element in `this`, all you need is the value of that `select` element.

```
$('#id_financial_institution').change(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#fi').text(value); //i assume `fi` is an [id]
  //do more stuff
});
```

Comment: also, if `#fi` is another `input`, `textarea`, or `select` element, you'll need to use `$('#fi').val(value)`

Comment: @refhat, OP doesn't specify what sort of selector `fi` is supposed to be. Typically when that happens it's because the programmer wants to use an `[id]`, which is why I made the assumption and promptly described it in the code.